# Better way to "combine" all combinations of multi-element indices from multiple lists in R?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, apply, mapply

Say I have two lists, each containing variable numbers of multiple sub-elements within multiple indexes:

```
list.a <- list(c("a","b","c"), c("x", "y", "z"))
list.b <- list(c("d", "e", "f","g"), c("m", "n"))
```

- This results in:

  ```
  > list.a
  [[1]]
  [1] "a" "b" "c"

  [[2]]
  [1] "x" "y" "z"
  ```

  and

  ```
  > list.b
  [[1]]
  [1] "d" "e" "f" "g" "h"

  [[2]]
  [1] "m" "n"
  ```

How do I recursively access each *combo* of sub-elements from the corresponding index from each list?

- For example, I want to access the combos of a-d, a-e, a-f, a-g, b-d, b-e,  ... and so on for the first index and x-m, x-n, y-m, y-n, z-m and z-n from the second index of each list.

  ```
  [[1]]
   [1] "a d" "a e" "a f" "a g" "b d" "b e" "b f" "b g" "c d" "c e" "c f" "c g"

  [[2]]
  [1] "x m" "x n" "y m" "y n" "z m" "z n"
  ```

`mapply` does not seem to work when I have multiple sub-elements from each list (especially if the number of elements is not equal from both lists):

```
> mapply(paste,list.a,list.b)
[[1]]
[1] "a d" "b e" "c f" "a g"

[[2]]
[1] "x m" "y n" "z m"
```

- It skips half of the combinations and instead just recycles the shorter of the two lists. I want it to combine *all* combinations within the shared index from both lists .

I know I could also use a `for` loop...:

```
list.d <- list()
for(i in 1:length(list.a)) {
  list.c <- list()
  list.d[[i]] <- {
    for(j in list.a[[i]]) {
      for(k in list.b[[i]]) {
       list.c <- c(list.c, paste(j, k))
      }
    }
    unlist(list.c)
    }
}
```

Which produces the desired result:

```
> list.d
[[1]]
 [1] "a d" "a e" "a f" "a g" "b d" "b e" "b f" "b g" "c d" "c e" "c f" "c g"

[[2]]
[1] "x m" "x n" "y m" "y n" "z m" "z n"
```

...BUT The loop is messy at best and becomes fairly slow with huge lists.

**Is there a better way to do this?**

- Specifically, is there a special function or some approach to using `apply` functions that would accomplish this task more efficiently for me?

---

---

< Application >

<sup>*(this part is not needed to answer the question, but provides context/extension of its use):*</sup>

For those curious, I want to extend this beyond `paste()` and instead want to use this on a data.frame.

- For example:

  Say I have two lists, each containing multiple indices with multiple  sub-elements:

  ```
  l1 <- list(c(1933:1935),c(1950:1954), c(2012:2013))  #groups of years
  l2 <- list(c(19:21),c(19:24),c(22:26))               #groups of plot numbers
  ```

  Let's also assume I have the folowing data.frame:

  ```
  dat <- data.frame(plot = rep(1:30,81), year = rep(1933:2013, each = 30), area = sample(270))

  > head(dat)
    plot year area
  1    1 1933  137
  2    2 1933   72
  3    3 1933  136
  4    4 1933  187
  5    5 1933  206
  6    6 1933   74
  ```

  I want to create a new list (we'll call it `l3`) that contains the summed area for all combinations of `l1` (years) and `l2` (plots) for each coinciding list index.

  - For example, the result for `[[1]]` of the resulting list would be the sum of the areas for plots 19, 20 *&* 21 for each of 1933, 1934 *&* 1935.

    The result for `[[2]]` would be the summed areas for plots 19 through 24 for each of the years 1950 through 1954.

Comment: I'm never quite sure how to reference the different parts of a list. I hope my questions makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `expand.grid`, it is used to:

> Create a data frame from all combinations of the supplied vectors or
>   factors.

use `do.call(paste, ...)` is to paste all columns of a data frame together.

```
Map(function(a,b) do.call(paste, expand.grid(a,b)), list.a, list.b)

#[[1]]
# [1] "a d" "b d" "c d" "a e" "b e" "c e" "a f" "b f" "c f" "a g" "b g" "c g"

#[[2]]
#[1] "x m" "y m" "z m" "x n" "y n" "z n"
```

---

For the second part of the question, we can subset the data frame by year and plots firstly and then aggregate *area* by *year* using *rowsum*:

```
Map(function(years, plots) {
    with(subset(dat, plot %in% plots & year %in% years), rowsum(area, year))
}, l1, l2)

[[1]]
     [,1]
1933  257
1934  398
1935  640

[[2]]
     [,1]
1950  950
1951  457
1952  601
1953 1202
1954 1148

[[3]]
     [,1]
2012  736
2013  497
```

Comment: Thanks @Psidom! How would I extend this beyond just `paste`? For example, how could I apply this approach to subsetting a data.frame? (see 2nd half of my question)

Comment: Do you want to aggregate by year or plot? Maybe `Map(function(years, plots) sum(subset(dat, plot %in% plots & year %in% years)$area), l1, l2)`?

Comment: I want to aggregate by year. But again, that's only if the plot is listed in the coinciding index of the other list.

Comment: If aggregate by year, try Map(function(years, plots) with(subset(dat, plot %in% plots & year %in% years), rowsum(area, year)),l1,l2)

Comment: Your code works great! Thanks, mate! If you incorporate the code from your comments to your answer (not overwrite the current answer, but add to it explaining each approach), I will gladly accept this as correct :D.